# Is it a good idea to return component from custom hook in React?

Tags: reactjs

In lots of cases, custom hooks are used to return just values or functions. Of course we can return component from custom hooks, but is it a good idea ?

What is the pros and cons to return component from custom hooks ?

Comment: I'm not sure what'd be the goal of returning a component from a Hook when you can just render a component from a component, and use the custom Hooks for what they are - a piece of reusable code stored in one place returning a function or state ready to be consumed around multiple components?

Comment: It might be useful for your custom hook to return a wrapper around a component that sets some default values for the supported props, particularly if those props are react components themselves.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, it depends on perspective, generally it is not a good idea as it violates the seperation of concerns concept because `hooks` are intended to give functionality, not `render`.

Further to say pros and cons:

Pros:

1. **Reusability:** You may package together specific UI functionality into a single hook and utilise it across several components by returning a component from a custom hook.
2. **Abstraction:** By returning a component from a hook, some implementation details can be hidden, improving the readability and maintainability of the code.
3. **Convenience:** On sometimes, returning a component from a hook may be more practical than passing it several props.

Cons:

1. **Confusing**: It might be more challenging to comprehend the data and control flow in your application when a component is returned from a hook. Those developers who are not familiar with the pattern may likewise find it puzzling.
2. **Testing**: Because it includes testing both the hook and the component, evaluating a component retrieved from a hook might be more difficult than testing a typical component.
3. **Performance**: If a hook-returned component is sophisticated and computationally intensive, rendering it may have an impact on performance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm tending to try this practice for sake of removing importing components and logic of their usage in the middle, where they don't belong. Seems to be good approach to reduce unnecessary code and encapsulating **how** to render what is returned from hook.
You can abstract what you need inside hooks or ignore returned component when you need